# Adding a currency sign with no spacing into a dictionary output in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to add a currency into my output from a dictionary. However, there is a spacing between my currency sign and the int.

```
foodItems = [{"name":"6 Apples", "price": 5.40},
            {"name": "Mixed Vegetables Pack 1kg", "price": 9.32},
            {"name": "Yakult 5 in a pack", "price": 3.20},
            {"name": "Mixed nuts 500g", "price": 16.98},
            {"name": "Milk Powder 200g", "price": 9.47},
            {"name": "Roasted Chicken Breast 1kg", "price": 8.56}]

#display food items
for i in foodItems:
    print("{:<41}${:>6.2f}".format(i["name"],i["price"]))
```

Output:

```
Food items available for subscription (price/week)
6 Apples                                 $  5.40
Mixed Vegetables Pack 1kg                $  9.32
Yakult 5 in a pack                       $  3.20
Mixed nuts 500g                          $ 16.98
Milk Powder 200g                         $  9.47
Roasted Chicken Breast 1kg               $  8.56
```

How do I remove the spacing between my "$" and the figure such that my output becomes

```
Food items available for subscription (price/week)
6 Apples                                     $5.40
Mixed Vegetables Pack 1kg                    $9.32
Yakult 5 in a pack                           $3.20
Mixed nuts 500g                             $16.98
Milk Powder 200g                             $9.47
Roasted Chicken Breast 1kg                   $8.56
```

Comment: just change `{:>6.2f}` to `{:0.2f}`

Comment: @JoranBeasley my figures have to right aligned to the last bracket.

Comment: What have you tried to get the output you need? It's trivial to obtain it by string formatting / concatenation once you understand [how string format specifiers work in Python.](https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/#the-format_spec-component)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will require two string format steps; one to add the dollar sign and format the floats correctly as currency, and one to right-align the text.

```
print("Food items available for subscription (price/week)")
#display food items
for i in foodItems:
    print("{:<41}{:>9}".format(i["name"], "${:.2f}".format(i["price"])))
```

**Output**

```
Food items available for subscription (price/week)
6 Apples                                     $5.40
Mixed Vegetables Pack 1kg                    $9.32
Yakult 5 in a pack                           $3.20
Mixed nuts 500g                             $16.98
Milk Powder 200g                             $9.47
Roasted Chicken Breast 1kg                   $8.56
```

Comment: thank you, i have managed to figure it out. i formatted the dollar sign first before formatting the float.